# Is (a sort of) converse to MVT True or False?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$. Then there are numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<c<b$ so that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$.

Is this true or false?

I'm pretty sure its false, but how can I show this? I think I can use the example $f'(c)=0$, but how would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x)=x^3$ with $c=0$ is a counterexample. This is so since $f'(c)=0$, but for all $a<c<b$ $f(b)-f(a)>0$, and hence $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>0\ne f'(c)$.

Comment: hmmm, could elaborate on how that proves the claim to be false?

Comment: @PaulGerard better?

Comment: yes, thank you. much appreciated