# If the derivative e $c$ in $\mathbb R$, then exist $a<b$ such that $f'(c)=(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

If the derivative e $c$ in $\mathbb R$, then exist $a<b$ such that $f'(c)=(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$. It´s true or false?

I think it's false, although it looks like the mean value theorem, note that this theorem guarantees the existence of a $c$ and not reals $a<b$, but how do I find a simple counterexample?
I thought of $f(x)=x^3$, but I can't justify it. Need some help with examples. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the context where you found this statement? A screenshot/picture of book/handout/worksheet etc?

Comment: This has been asked and answer before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369243/42969. (And the counterexample is $f(x) = x^3$ with $c=0$.)

Comment: Is on an exam at the faculty of science at the university of Porto

Comment: there are no more counterexamples, odd degree monomials will do?

Comment: There are surely many more counterexamples. E.g. all strictly increasing functions with a stationary point. $f(x) = \sin(x)$ with $c=0$ is another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: what does "if the derivative e $c$ in $\Bbb R$" mean???

Comment: "e" = "and", in portuguese, i'm sorry